# Trying jQuery wrapAll seems to wrap the content twice

Tags: jquery, wrapall

I got a markup looking like this :

```
<body>
    <...
    a lot of tags from the web site
    ...>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.1.1/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="my_script.js"></script>
<body>
```

I want it to end up that way :

```
<body>
    <div id="body-content">
        <...
        a lot of tags from the web site
        ...>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.1.1/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="my_script.js"></script>
    </div>
    <div id="isolated-component">
</div>
<body>
```

So I can populate #isolated-component and easily discard them from a jQuery selection.

I tried that :

```
jQuery("body").children().wrapAll("<div id='body-content'></div>")
                        .after("<div id='isolated-component'></div>");
```

But ended up with :

```
<html>
<head>
<body>
    <div id="body-content">
        <div id="body-content">
            <... page content ...>
        </div>
        <div id="isolated-component"/>
        <div id="isolated-component"/>
    </div>
    <script src="my_script.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
</body>
<div id="_firebugConsole" style="display: none;" FirebugVersion="1.4.3" methodName="log"/>
</html>
```

Comment: In what context is your code being called. The script may be getting called inside an event that is being raised twice but I can't tell from what you included.

Comment: You know that you're actually on stackoverflow right now?

Comment: Lol, sorry. I posted this to Doctype as well, I wanted to try this new site :-)

Comment: if anyone nat to compare the anwser from one site to another : 

http://doctype.com/trying-jquery-wrapall-seems-wrap-content-twice#answer_2067

I tend to prefer the SO interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found why. When you move the body content to the DIV, it moves the script tags including the JS moving the stuff and lead the script to execute a second time. Now I don't know why this doesn't end up in a infinite loop, but it's good to know : don't ever move script tags, you will make them reload.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will fix your problem but you should use [`wrapInner`](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/wrapInner#html):

```
jQuery("body").wrapInner("<div id='body-content'></div>")
    .after("<div id='isolated-component'></div>");
```