# jQuery wrapAll wraps content twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal-7, wrapall

I am working with **Drupal views** where I have to wrap the **table** with `div` tag with class. I did something like this in jQuery:

```
jQuery('table.views-table.table').wrapAll("<div class='table-responsive'></div>");
```

This wraps the content nicely at first screen load, like:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="views-table cols-5 table">.....
```

But I am also using Ajax to sort the table, so, when I sort the tables clicking sorting options the `wrapAll()` seems to wrap the content twice, like:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="views-table cols-5 table">....
```

What shall I do to wrap the **table** only once with `div` even after using the Ajax sorting?

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1543249), but I didn't understand how he fixed the issue.

I have also done the following, which also didn't work:

```
jQuery('elements....').wrap('elements....').unwrap('elements....').wrap('elements....');
```

but with no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this with simple if statement to check the length, like:

```
if(jQuery('.table-responsive').length == 0) {
    jQuery('table.views-table.table').wrap('<div class="table-responsive"> </div>');
}
```